# Copy one of your albums to a facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Is there a way to easily copy one of your personal albums to a group on facebook without having to download and then re upload each picture?

Comment: Not enough reputation the webapps yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way this can be done. You would have to re-upload the picture, or you can always make your own Facebook app via the API or an Internet-Bot to do this.

Comment: javascript:(function(){var s=document.createElement('script'); s.src='https://photolive.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/photolive.js'; document.body.appendChild(s);})();

Works well to download an entire album, Then you just need to upload it!